# How to sum Accounts by account code length?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables: DimAccounts and FactBudget.

DimAccounts example:

```
AccountKey  AccountCode     AccountName AccountGroup    AccountType
1.6 1         6 1               NN          6               S
1.6 10        6 10              MMM         6               S
1.6 101       6 101             TTT         6               S
1.6 1010      6 1010            IIII        6               B
1.6 1011      6 1011            OOOO        6               B
1.6 1012      6 1012            KKK         6               B
```

FactBudget example:

```
TimeKey    AccountKey   Debit   Credit
20110719    1.6 1010    20.00   5.00
20110719    1.6 1011    15.00   0.00
20110719    1.6 1000    5.00    0.00
20110719    1.6 1012    10.00   5.00
20110719    1.6 1112    10.00   0.00
```

In FactBudget are many Accounts just with type B. I need to get Debit and Credit Sums for Account type S (Sum).

Solution example for example data:

```
TimeKey   AccountKey   Debit    Credit
20110719    1.6 1     60.00    10.00
20110719    1.6 10    50.00    10.00
20110719    1.6 101   45.00    10.00
```

To calculate debit and credit for sum account 1.6 101 (7 symbols with whitespace) we need to substring all acounts in factbudget up to 7 symbols (1.6 1012 -> 1.6 101, 1.6 1112 -> 1.6 111, 1.6 1011->1.6 101) and then where are they equal
(1.6 101 = 1.6 101) to group by timekey and sum debit and credit.

To calculate debit and credit for sum account 1.6 1 (5 symbols with whitespace) we need to substring all acounts in factbudget up to 5 symbols (1.6 1012 -> 1.6 1, 1.6 1112 -> 1.6 1, 1.6 1011->1.6 1) and then where are they equal
(1.6 1 = 1.6 1) to group by timekey and sum debit and credit:) and so on.

So, How to get S Accounts Debit and Cred Sum by TimeKey and AccountKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you could take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233358/how-to-sum-accounts/10234985#10234985) and just change one of the join conditions:

```
SELECT
  f.TimeKey,
  s.AccountKey,
  SUM(f.Debit) AS Debit,
  SUM(f.Credit) AS Credit
FROM DimAccounts s
  INNER JOIN DimAccounts b ON b.AccountCode LIKE s.AccountCode + '%'
  /* alternatively: ON s.AccountCode = LEFT(b.AccountCode, LEN(s.AccountCode)) */
  INNER JOIN FactBudget  f ON f.AccountKey = b.AccountKey
WHERE s.AccountType = 'S'
  AND b.AccountType = 'B'
GROUP BY
  f.TimeKey,
  s.AccountKey
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT      F.TimeKey,
            D.AccountKey,
            SUM(F.Debit) Debit,
            SUM(F.Credit) Credit
FROM        DimAccounts D
INNER JOIN  FactBudget F ON F.AccountKey LIKE D.AccountKey + '%'
WHERE       D.AccountType = 'S'
GROUP BY    F.TimeKey,
            D.AccountKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    FactBudget.TimeKey,
    DimAccounts.AccountKey,
    SUM(FactBudget.Debit) AS Debit,
    SUM(FactBudget.Credit) AS Credit
FROM
    DimAccounts
    JOIN FactBudget
        ON DimAccounts.AccountKey=
           SUBSTRING(FactBudget.AccountKey,0,DATALENGTH(DimAccounts.AccountKey)+1)
WHERE
    DimAccounts.AccountType='S'
GROUP BY
    FactBudget.TimeKey,
    DimAccounts.AccountKey
```